# make OCSP response unique

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, bouncycastle, digital-certificate, ocsp

I sign document with PADES LTV Profile. Signer library is written base on Pdfbox library.

I have one problem.

In PADES LTV  profile, the final revision must be checked in online (It means that OCSP responses, CRLS and certificates of this revision must not be in document secure store (DSS)).

For testing, I add 12 revision to my document.

Every time when I add **new** revision, I do **not** add certificates and ocsp responses of this **current** revision to the DSS. I add previous revisions certificates and ocsp responses to the DSS. I do this because last revision **must be checked in online**. So I must not add OCSP response of last revision to the DSS.  I do so, but sometimes Adobe reader thinks that last revision have  **embedded** OCSP response in the document.

**The problem might be is that following:**

Each ocsp response must be unique, even if when we generate them with  the same certificate. In the other words, If we request ocsp object twice, they must be unique.

For this I do that following but it does not work:

```
private OCSPReq buildOcspRequest(X509Certificate issuerCert, BigInteger serialNumber, File inputDocument) {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputDocument);
    X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder;

    certificateHolder = new X509CertificateHolder(issuerCert.getEncoded());
    CertificateID id = new CertificateID(new BcDigestCalculatorProvider().get(CertificateID.HASH_SHA1), certificateHolder, serialNumber);

    OCSPReqBuilder ocspReqBuilder = new OCSPReqBuilder();
    ocspReqBuilder.addRequest(id);

    DigestCalculatorProvider digestCalculatorProvider;
    JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder digestCalcProvBuilder = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC");
    digestCalculatorProvider = digestCalcProvBuilder.build();

    // get SHA 256 
    DigestCalculator digest = digestCalculatorProvider.get(AlgorithmIdentifier.getInstance("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1")); 

    OutputStream os = digest.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(is, os);

    byte[] messageImprint = digest.getDigest();

    BigInteger time = BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // time + imprint
    byte[] nonce = ArrayUtils.addAll(time.toByteArray(), messageImprint);

    Extension extension = new Extension(OCSPObjectIdentifiers.id_pkix_ocsp_nonce, true, nonce);
    ocspReqBuilder.setRequestExtensions(new Extensions(extension));

    return ocspReqBuilder.build();

}
```

this is testing pdf link [SAMPLE PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1IQEoiXFg3IazNBNnlucElxUVk/edit?usp=sharing)

I might create 4 revision and everything might be all right ... I don't know , sometimes it happens...  When I was testing,  the problem occours when I create many revisions...  **THE LAST REVISION THINKS THAT OCSP RESPONSE OF PREVIOUS REVISIONS IS IT'S OWN!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In PADES LTV profile, the final revision must be checked in online

No.

PAdES, i.e. ETSI TS 102 778, in [part 4 (PAdES-LTV Profile)](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.01_60/ts_10277804v010101p.pdf) merely **recommends** this:

> > 4.3 Validation Process
> >
> > It is recommended that that validation process be as follows:
> >
> > 1) The "latest" document Time-stamp should be validated at current time with validation data collected at the current time.

The word **should** indicates a recommendation, and the sentence before actually spells it out.

But let's assume you want to follow the recommendation. Your interpretation

> (It means that OCSP responses, CRLS and certificates of this revision must not be in document secure store (DSS)).

is not correct still: There may be validation related information (OCSP responses, CRLs, certificates) in the document which (seen as isolated information) apply to the outer time stamp or signature. If you time stamp your document twice in short succession using the same time stamp service and add a CRL for certificates used in the first time stamp in the time between, chances are that the outer time stamp involves certificates covered by this CRL and is applied in the validity interval indicated by the CRL.

No, it is the **responsibility of the verifier not to use these information** if the verifier chose to follow the PAdES-LTV recommendation quoted above.

Adobe Reader does *not* claim to follow this recommendation (at least as far as I know). Thus, if you verify the signatures and time stamps using Adobe Reader, information contained in the document may be used to verify the outer time stamp, too.

Actually Adobe originally loved the concept of first retrieving validation related information and signing and time stamping everything including those information thereafter.

> **The problem might be is that following:**
>
> Each ocsp response must be unique, even if when we generate them with the same certificate. In the other words, If we request ocsp object twice, they must be unique.

No. While it is good style to use nonces, your observation has nothing to do with them.

The reason why Adobe Reader *sometimes* (and *only sometimes*) makes use of already embedded information for verifying outer signatures / time stamps is that OCSP responses and CRLs have validity intervals defined by their `thisUpdate` and `nextUpdate` fields which *sometimes* (if you add multiple time stamps by the same TSA) in spite of being embedded for the validation of an older time stamp still encompass the time of the newly added one (and, thus, are also used for their validation).

If you want to prevent this, you have to check the OCSP responses and CRLs already contained in the PDF or just now added to it by you, inspect those whose respective validity interval has not yet ended, and not apply any time stamp to the document whose certificates can be validated with them.

Comment: "The "latest" document Time-stamp should be validated at current time with validation data collected at the current time." BUT , In order to collect data at the current  time you must check it in the online (4.3 validation process). does not it? :) I understand this so...

Comment: I might not prevent this everytime. For instance if I have 10 revision in the document. and the "latest" one is checking to the online. If I add new revision without adding certificates,ocsps and crls  in the DSS, the previous revision will not be LTV enabled. Also If I add some ocsp, crls which is need for previous revision to be LTV enabled, this might make the "latest" revision LTV enabled too.

In Conclusion, there is no way to prevent this ... If I need to prevent this, I must not add time stamp to the document for the current time (until nextUpdate). does not it?

Comment: *BUT , In order to collect data at the current time you must check it in the online (4.3 validation process)* - no, it says **should** which is way different from **must**.

Comment: *If I need to prevent this, I must not add time stamp to the document for the current time (until nextUpdate)* - or use a different tsa. Or make Adobe change their verification policies.